# AKS enable-pod-identity fails with DevOps error

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, azure-managed-identity

I have a node.js app running in AKS and needs to access a Key Vault. I have used Deployment center in the K8s service to set up DevOps. By mistake I did the setup in Deployment center twice which lead to two copies of .yml files (deploytoAksCluster.yml and deploytoAksCluster-1.yml). I have fixed this, but when I run the following command to enable pod identity I get an error.

```
az aks update -g $resource_group -n $k8s_name --enable-pod-identity
```

**Error:**

> (BadRequest) Tag name cannot be hidden-DevOpsInfo:GH:my-GithubOrg/myApplication:main:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:59a0dfdb:my-akscluster:1646402646541.43;GH:my-GithubOrg/myApplication:main:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:13350477:my-akscluster:1646924094935.21; or be longer than 512 characters. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags for more details.

Currently I have only one workflow in GitHub (deploytoAksCluster.yml), but the error with reference to deploytoAksCluster-1.yml never goes away.

I have used this sample as inspiration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity#run-a-sample-application

**What I have tried**

- removed the duplicate files
- reintroduce the duplicate files
- delete the deployment

This is how AKS Deployment center looks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziFEk.png

**Update**

59a0dfdb referers to a git commit. This commit resulted in a failed workflow. The workflow has been fixed and everything deploys nicely to K8s, but --enable-pod-identity keeps complaining with the above error. I have removed the commit from github history.
I have even removed the repository in github.
Must be a git history somewhere in k8s that --enable-pod-identity is hung up on somehow?

Comment: the error is saying the tag name is too long, have you tried removing this tag or make it shorter ? looks like it s auto generated tag ?

Comment: The problem was actually the tag name. The tag name was set to: "hidden-DevOpsInfo:GH:my-GithubOrg/myApplication:main:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:59a0dfdb:my-akscluster:1646402646541.43;GH:my-GithubOrg/myApplication:main:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:13350477:my-akscluster:1646924094935.21"

Thank you @Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Please retry deleting the deployment cluster  again as in some cases trying twice removed the required cluster which is not required .
Also check if corresponding resource group is deleted and clear the cache .

Try update the git version depending on the type of OS you are using.

Also

> **NOTE :** If you're using existing resources when you're creating a new cluster, such as an IP address or route table, az aks create
> overwrites the set of tags. If you delete that cluster later, *any tags
> set by the cluster will be removed.*

from [Azure tags on an AKS cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/aks/use-tags)

To update the tags on an existing cluster, we need to run az aks update with the --tags parameter.

**Reference**

[errors when trying to create update scale delete or upgrade cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#im-receiving-errors-when-trying-to-create-update-scale-delete-or-upgrade-cluster-that-operation-is-not-allowed-as-another-operation-is-in-progress)

Comment: Thank you. Updating the tag did the trick

Comment: I did upvote, but my stackoverflow ranking is not good enough to make any change...

Answer (score 1):

The tag name of the cluster was auto generated to "hidden-DevOpsInfo:GH:my-GithubOrg/myApplication:main:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:59a0dfdb:my-akscluster:1646402646541.43;GH:my-GithubOrg/myApplication:main:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:deploytoAksCluster-1.yml:13350477:my-akscluster:1646924094935.21".
The solution was in the error message: "Tag name cannot be..."

I got the tags by running:
`az aks show -g $resource_group -n $k8s_name --query '[tags]'` 
and updated the tag with:
`az aks update --resource-group $resource_group --name $k8s_name --tags "key"="Value"`